# VBA TextBox pass value of each line to cell range

Tags: excel, textbox, multiline, vba

A user pastes values from a spreadsheet into a multiline TextBox. TextBox will look like this (tab delimited by default):

[image: TextBox]

So each line has 3 values, SKU, Qty, Price separated by 2 tabs in between.
(sometimes values of Qty or Price may be omitted).

Now trying to pass each value of each line into 3 dedicated cells, J1 K1 and L1.

Final result should look like image below. (Cells will be overwritten with values of next line)

[image: Results]

Code I have so far is successful in passing the values of each line to a MsgBox.

```
Sub passValuesToCell()    

    UserForm1.TextBox25.SetFocus
    lines = UserForm1.TextBox25.LineCount
    For i = 0 To lines - 1
        MsgBox Split(UserForm1.TextBox25, Chr(13))(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

How do I rework the code to pass values into J1 K1 L1? Tried this bus but errored out

```
 Sub passMultiSkuToCell()
 Dim a() As String

    UserForm1.TextBox25.SetFocus
    lines = UserForm1.TextBox25.LineCount
    For i = 0 To lines - 1
        a() = Split(UserForm1.TextBox25, Chr(13))(i)
        Range("J1").Resize(UBound(a) + 1, 1).Value = a()
    Next

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `SetFocus` and `LineCount`; you can get the number of lines by first splitting by `vbLf`, then you split each line by `vbTab`. Try this:

```
Sub passValuesToCell()
    Dim lines: lines = Split(UserForm1.TextBox25.value, vbLf)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(lines)
        Sheet1.Range("J" & i + 1).Resize(, 3).value = Split(lines(i), vbTab)
    Next
End Sub
```

p.s. if you want to overwrite the lines on the same cells `J1 K1 L1` (which I failed to see the reason, but well) then simply replace `"J" & i + 1` by `"J1"`.

Comment: A.S.H. this one works very well in spiting up the tabbed values into adjacent cells, but it copies ALL lines at once into cells J1 J2 etc. accordingly. What I need is to do line by line and overwrite J1 K1 L1.

Comment: @joell then replace `"J" & i + 1` by `"J1"`.

Comment: Closer! Now how do I run another macro between each input of rows to the cells? This is the reason I wanted to designate only these cells, while the macro will parse the values of these cells, each time differently. Sorry not pointing that out.

Comment: A.S.H working now like a charm, just added the macro before Next. God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the Delimiter and the StartAddress to fit your needs.
You can change the NumCols to 3 if you wish to hardcode it.

The code below will paste each row to the destination using a String Array and the Offset command.

```
Sub passValuesToCell()
  ' Set active worksheet
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

  ' Set delimiter
  Dim myDelimiter As String
  myDelimiter = Chr(13)

  ' Initial array with lines
  Dim lines(1 To 3) As String
  lines(1) = "ABC" & myDelimiter & "10" & myDelimiter & "20"
  lines(2) = "DEF" & myDelimiter & "20" & myDelimiter & "30"
  lines(3) = "GHI" & myDelimiter & "30" & myDelimiter & "40"

  ' Temporary array to get each line
  Dim NumRows As Long: NumRows = UBound(lines, 1) - LBound(lines, 1) + 1 ' Row Count - your LineCount
  Dim NumCols As Long: NumCols = UBound(Split(lines(1), myDelimiter)) + 1 ' Column count - you can hardcode it to 3

  ' Set the destination to start from
  Dim StartAddress As String: StartAddress = "A1"

  ' Set destination range to be 1 row and with NumCols columns
  Dim MyDestination As Range: Set MyDestination = sht.Range(StartAddress).Resize(1, NumCols)

  For i = 1 To NumRows
    MyDestination.Value = Split(lines(i), myDelimiter) ' Split lines to the current destination
    Set MyDestination = MyDestination.Offset(1, 0) ' go to next row in destination range
  Next i
End Sub
```